# how to install pandas on python3.3.2 win 32 bit (win10)?

Tags: pandas, numpy, python-3.3

Considering that only Python version 3.3.2 (32-bit) is compatible with Digsilent software (version 15.1). I have to install only this version. Now, to work with data (data manipulation) in an Excel file, I need to install the Pandas module.

I could not find a compatible version of the Pandas library with Python 3.3.2 (32-bit).

My operating system is Windows 10 and I have installed version 1.10.1 of numpy library. Please introduce the compatible version of the Pandas library with Python 3.3.2 (32-bit) (where can I get it?) and also, considering that this version of Python does not support the pip module, how to install it Describe it (name the necessary prerequisites for installing this module).

Can anyone guide me? Thank you

Comment: You can always install an alternative version of Python and other libraries using a virtual environment using `virtualenv` or `conda`. Don't stick with the old version to process the data; it could cause a neverending headache.